# How to unit test Durable Functions with errors and retry

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-functions, moq, azure-durable-functions

I've read these two Microsoft documentation on Unit Testing and Error Handling

Unit testing:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-unit-testing

Error handling - with the retry
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-error-handling?tabs=csharp

What I am trying to do in my unit test the following:

1) have activity throw exception

2) verify Orchestrator will call `CallActivityRetryAsync` based on my retry options, e.g. 3 times

3) verify my try/catch block catches the exception once and my error handler is called. (aside: is the exception wrapped in a `FunctionFailedException`?)

So for example, based on the MS documentation, if this is my orchestrator:

```
    [FunctionName("E1_HelloSequence")]
    public static async Task<List<string>> Run(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
    try
    {
        var outputs = new List<string>();
        var retryOptions = new RetryOptions(
                firstRetryInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                maxNumberOfAttempts: 3);


        outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityRetryAsync<string>("E1_SayHello", retryOptions, "Tokyo"));
        outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityRetryAsync<string>("E1_SayHello", retryOptions, "Seattle"));


        // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!"]
        return outputs;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("E1_SayHello", "I Failed..."));
            throw;
    }
    }

    [FunctionName("E1_SayHello")]
    public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context)
    {
        string name = context.GetInput<string>();
        return $"Hello {name}!";
    }
```

And my test would be something like this:

```
public class HelloSequenceTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Run_returns_multiple_greetings()
    {
        var mockContext = new Mock<IDurableOrchestrationContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(x => x.CallActivityRetryAsync<string>("E1_SayHello", "Tokyo")).ReturnsAsync("Hello Tokyo!");
        mockContext.Setup(x => x.CallActivityRetryAsync<string>("E1_SayHello", "Seattle")).ReturnsAsync("Hello Seattle!");

        var result = await HelloSequence.Run(mockContext.Object);

        Assert.Equal(2, result.Count);
        Assert.Equal("Hello Tokyo!", result[0]);
        Assert.Equal("Hello Seattle!", result[1]);
    }
}
```

So in the example above, how would I

1) have the Activity `E1_SayHello` thrown an exception

2) verify that there were 3 retries

3) verify that my catch block executed once?

Comment: Is the interface `IDurableOrchestrationContext`something you implement? If that is out of your scope you cannot test it and you should not since that module should be tested by its own...

Comment: @Johnny The IDurableOrchestrationContext is part of the azure durable function framework. He's trying to test the retry policies like you can do with Polly retries to make sure the flow is accurate. I'm trying to currently solve the same problem